# group by all except aggregation functions

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I have a select statement like

```
select field1
,field2
,field3
count(field4)
from (
   ...subquery...
)
```

this is a pretty primitive minimization of my statement.

What I need is a way to include the `count(field4)` definition
WITHOUT having to declare `field1` - `field3` in a group by clause.

Because this is all dynamic and I can't say how many fields will be
selected in the statement and how many aggregation function will be 
in the statement.

So in need a generic form of group by clause that groups by everything but
the aggregation functions and possibly except a number of specified columns that are not supposed to be grouped.

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: If it is dynamic, why can't you just put the columns in that you need?

Comment: select distinct, with a correlated sub-query.

Comment: If something is generating the columns in the select, why can't it be used to do the same in the `GROUP BY` clause ?

Comment: i could actually do that but its more a convenients thing. the source code would look like a mess with the language im using

Answer (score 0):

Do the COUNT in the SUBQUERY with an ALIAS, then call the ALIAS from the SELECT statement:

`select field1
,field2
,field3
countfield4
from (
   ...subquery... count(field4) AS countfield4
)`